# How can I point a total row or total column using pointer in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

For example: I have a file that contains some text..like

```
my name is sunny
i am a student
```

i want to read from file and store it like,

```
a[0][0]=my,a[0][1]=name,a[0][2]=is,a[0][3]=sunny,

a[1][0]=i,a[1][1]=am,a[1][2]=a,a[1][3].
```

How can I do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: all lines have exactly 4 words?

Answer (score 1):

You can use fgets to read each line of text. For each line read, you increment the counter you use to access `a` first dimmension (rows). And for each read line you use strtok to iterate over all tokens in the line. For each token strtok returns you should attribute the pointer to `a[i][j]` and increment `j`.

Of course, `a` is a pointer to char matriz.

Comment: Even if they are separated by some other character than space, you can always list all possible ones in the call to strtok

Answer (score 0):

well, im going to give you some clues.

First declare  `a`  as

```
char a[2][3];
```

This variable can be used like this:

```
int main()
{
   char a[2][3];

   a[1][1]='a';
   printf("%c",a[1][1]);

}
```

Then use  `fscanf(f, "%c", a[][]);`  to read from file, see internet tutorials and manual pages for this.

Other option is to do it dinamically:

Declare  `a`  as:

```
char **a;
```

After that, you alloc memory like this:

```
a = (char**)malloc(2 * sizeof(char*));  //Two times the size of char
```

Now you have the memory for the first array, we want to "insert" into each space of the array another array. Think in it like a matrix.

```
for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    a[i] = (char*)malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
```

This give you your matrix. Use it like the first case.

The case of the question read strings, so try to do the same with this struct instead of char

```
typedef struct string {
    char cadena[6];
}myString;
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't teste it. It's just a example how to do it.

```
/* not real value; see limits.h header if you are in POSIX or equivalento to your env */
#define LINE_MAX 128
char line[LINE_MAX + 1];
char contents[MAX_LINES][MAX_WORDS];
char * token;
/* read file line by line */
while(fgets(line, LINE_MAX, fp) != NULL) {
 /* split words by white-space */
 token = strtok(buffer, " ");
 while(token != NULL) {
   // token is "my", after "name" and and so on.
   // store it into contents array. you can use strcpy() or strncpy() (more safe) 
 }
}
```